# Symfony Gitlab CI/CD deployment without overwritting images in public folder

Tags: linux, apache, symfony, ssh, gitlab-ci

I am currently using this script to deploy my symfony application to the webserver:

```yaml
Deploy:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" >> ~/.ssh/config'
  script:
    - zip -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA.zip .
    - scp -p $CI_COMMIT_SHA.zip $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST:/var/www/$PROJECT_FOLDER/
    - ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "cd  /var/www/$PROJECT_FOLDER/ && unzip -q $CI_COMMIT_SHA.zip -d $CI_COMMIT_SHA && rm $CI_COMMIT_SHA.zip && ln -sfn $CI_COMMIT_SHA current && exit"
```

The issue is that this script is overwritting the complete structure and therefore deleting uploaded images which are stored in /public/images/users.

What would be the best way to ignore this directory or prevent this directory from being overwritten?

Also considered to move images out of the folder before they are overwritten and move them back afterwards but I think this will create unnecessary load, especially with more and more files.

Comment: i would say to use a folder outside the public folder an build a symlink to the images path at the end of the deployment, would be the easiest way.

Comment: @SubCore Thank you for your suggestion but I dont get it do work. Symfony doesnt seem to support symlinks. My created link is working but then Symfony isnt able to write files in it. I searched for another solution and tried adding a mounting point with `mount --bind <src> <dest>` but this didnt work.

Comment: We use this symlink strategy in all our systems with tons of image files. If Symfony can't access the folder, its a permmission problem, not a Symfony problem.